# webform submitted by the user the email that is sent is wrapped after around 75 characters

Tags: webforms

I am using a Drupal 7 webform and when the webform is submitted by the user the email that is sent is wrapped after around 75 characters.  The confirmation page which is displayed and uses the same elements as the webform does not wrap after 75 but instead continue on the same line.
How can I get the webform email that is sent to not wrap after 75 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DefaultMailSystem::format](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.mail.inc/function/DefaultMailSystem%3A%3Aformat/7) uses drupal_wrap_mail() to wrap the body text on sending. There is no option to send unwrapped text.

Comment: Would it be possible to use hook_mail_alter to adjust the size of a line before the email is sent to the user?

Comment: The wrapping happens during send after all the hooks have been called. So no.